# Cant print this Json, Python

Tags: python, json

So I am saving data as a json file that is **Structured like so:**

```
{
"Users": [
{
  "BOB": [
    {
      "Computer Name": "Bob Pc",
      "Manufacturer": "Dell Inc.",
      "Make": "Precision Tower 3620",
      "Os": "Microsoft Windows 10 Pro",
      "Cpu": "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz",
      "Memory": "8589934592",
      "Slots": "4",
      "Used Slots": "1"
    }
  ] 
},
{
  "Sally": [
    {
      "Computer Name": "Sally PC",
      "Manufacturer": "Dell Inc.",
      "Make": "Precision Tower 3620",
      "Os": "Microsoft Windows 10 Pro",
      "Cpu": "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz",
      "Memory": "8589934592",
      "Slots": "4",
      "Used Slots": "1"
    }
      ]
}
  ]
}
```

If I want to **print** the whole thing I can do

```
with open(filename) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    print(data)
```

That will do it but now what if I want to **print all the info in "Bob"?**

I Tried:

```
print(data["Users"]["Bob"])
```

Which gives an error **list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Comment: `print(data["Users"][0])` ?

Comment: `print(data["Users]["Bob"])` Is badly quoted, missing a closing quote after Users.

Comment: In this json `"Users"` is a list of obects. You're trying to access to object incide list in wrong way.

Comment: @Rakesh This seems to only print the full second part so Sally's

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Sorry fixed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by its member inside a List in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858575/find-object-by-its-member-inside-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name = 'BOB'
for item in data["Users"]:
    if name in item.keys():
        print(item)
```

output:

```
{'BOB': [{'Computer Name': 'Bob Pc', 'Manufacturer': 'Dell Inc.', 'Make': 'Precision Tower 3620', 'Os': 'Microsoft Windows 10 Pro', 'Cpu': 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz', 'Memory': '8589934592', 'Slots': '4', 'Used Slots': '1'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of ncica works well. The other option is to convert `data` to the format you expect.

```
users = {name_: dict_ for user in data['users'] for name_, dict_ in user.items()}
print(users["Bob"])
```